# Continuity of characteristic function

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

Problem: Let $G$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $\chi_G$ is continuous on $G\cup(\mathbb{R}\backslash\overline{G})$. Consequently, $\chi_G$ is continuous a.e. on $\mathbb{R}$.

My Attempt:
Let $\epsilon>0$. There is a $\delta>0$ such that for every $x, y\in G$, $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|\chi_G(x)-\chi_G(y)|=|1-1|=0>\epsilon$. Hence $\chi_G$ is continuous on $G$.

Also, $\mathbb{R}\backslash \overline{G}$ is open, so for every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}\backslash \overline{G}$ and $|x- y|<\delta$ then $|\chi_G(x)-\chi_G(y)|=|0-0|=0>\epsilon$. Thus $\chi_G$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\backslash \overline{G}$.

But how will I show that $\chi_G$ is continuous on the union? Also continuity a.e. on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Did you know that any open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of open intervals?

Comment: yes I am aware of that.

Comment: You've already shown continuity on the union! Continuity on a set just means continuity at every point of the set, and every point of a union of two sets is in one set or the other. (Continuity is a local condition.)

Comment: I see, thank you very much!

Comment: @Greg: He hasn't actually shown $\chi$ to be continuous at any point of the union -- some muttering about continuity being a local condition along with the openness of the two subsets needs to be said. The missing piece is *routine* thing that could go without saying amongst people who know the subject well, but probably needs to be made explicit with people who still aren't comfortable with it.

Answer (score 2):

The function $\chi_G$ need not be continuous a.e. on $\mathbb R.$ To see this, choose an open $G$ that contains the rationals with $m(G)  < 1.$ Then $\chi_G$ is discontinuous at each point of $\mathbb R \setminus G,$ which is a set of infinite measure.